# Add date to datagridview from datatable created from MySQL as dd-MM-yyyy

Tags: vb.net

I have a webservice that selects * from a table and fills a datatable, that datatable is then returned to the app and bound as the datasource for the datagridview.
My problem is that several date columns returned are formatted as yyyy-MM-dd including the time.

Datagridview DefaultCellStyle.Format is also no good, because when I create a rdlc report, the date format is still yyyy-MM-dd.

How can I format the date to dd-MM-yyyy before it gets added to the datatable on the webservice? Currently it just selects * and fills the datatable with everything and returns it.

Language is VB.Net

Comment: `How can I format the date to dd-MM-yyyy before it gets added to the datatable on the webservice?`  You don't.  You format at the display level, so look at the CellFormatting event.

Comment: Wrong. If you want to format the data in the grid, format it in the grid. If you want to format it in the report, format it in the report.

Comment: In the DB, are the date fields stored as dates, in which case they should all appear the same & just apply formatting as needed, or are they stored as stings (shouldn't be but worth checking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bit doesn't make sense:

> I have a webservice that selects * from a table and fills a datatable, that datatable is then returned to the app and bound as the datasource for the datagridview. My problem is that several date columns returned are formatted as yyyy-MM-dd including the time.

A date column (viz. a column whose datatype is DATE or DATETIME) holds a representation of the date in some internal, numerical representation. It doesn't have a format; your computer has a date format. You look at your datatable in a debugger/UI and see yyyy-MM-dd because that's what the debugger formatted the date to before it displayed it, possibly with refernce to the system locale/culture settings. Your web service returned you a datatable with date type columns and they are formatless.

If you want them to have a particular format you set the format as a property of the cellstyle of the datagridviewcolumn:

```
 dataGrid.Columns(x).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd-MM-yyyy"
```

> Datagridview DefaultCellStyle.Format is also no good, because when I create a rdlc report, the date format is still yyyy-MM-dd.

That's right; because you're passing the datatable to the RDLC, and not the datagridview. It's the report's job to format the data appropriately from the datetime that it is in the table, to a string suited to the region the report is being run in. Something like:

```
=Format(whatever!SomeDateColumn,"dd-MM-yyyy")
```

Please don't make the webservice do the formatting of the date to a string; it makes everything harder work in other places if the back end low level layers are stringifying everything to some fixed format, when it should be the front end/presentation layer's job

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response, unfortunately when i use =Format(whatever!SomeDateColumn,"dd-MM-yyyy") on the report, some of the dates show as #error

Comment: What do you notice that is consistent about the dates that error? Might also be worth calling WriteXml on your datatable, saving it to disk as XML and posting a snippet of it up huere. Include a date that works and a date that errors ?

Comment: The dates which error all have the day greater than 09.
I've uploaded an image to imgBB, it will be easier if you see what I mean
https://ibb.co/tm425YQ

Comment: for example :- (day/month/year)
01/03/2020 - Would not error
07/12/2020 - Would not error
12/03/2020 - Get #ERROR

Comment: That is indeed odd. The only thing I can think that would be related is if the date were in fact a string in, say, dd-MM and were being implicitly parsed to date as if it were MM-dd (before the report tries to explicitly format it as dd-MM), so the 13th would be an error but the 12th not (12th mar as a string of 12-03 could implicitly parse as 3rd dec, but 13-03 will not parse). This conflicts with most of what you've said though. How's that "writing the datatable to xml and posting a snippet of the xml with a working date and a broken date" coming along?

Comment: Hi, here is the XML of a date which works and a date which errors

 works =  <DateDue>2020-12-02T08:00:00+00:00</DateDue>
get error = <DateDue>2020-12-25T08:00:00+00:00</DateDue>

Comment: I have figured it out... you were right it was picking it up as a string instead of a datatype date, I added columns to the datatable manually as specific datatypes and now it works, thank you so much for your help!!